# Xlsxwriter - multiindex column formatting

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am struggling with the problem - I use xlsxwriter for manipulating with Excel files. But one of my functions, which creates pivot table (see the code below) does not save excel normally - after saving the file, it says this warning:
[image]
[image]

Here is my code:

```
for i,value in enumerate(df.columns.get_level_values(0).values):
                    format_arr = split_format(columns_format, value)
                    format_cols = book.add_format({'align' : format_arr['align'], 'number_format' : format_arr['number_format'], 'font_color' : format_arr['font_color']})
                    format_header = book.add_format({'align' : format_arr['header_align'], 'bold' : True, 'border' : 2})
                    sheet.write(0, i, value, format_header)
                    sheet.set_column(i,i,format_arr['width'],format_cols)
```

df represents pd.pivot_table() output with multiindex. Can you, please, advice me, how to correctly apply formats for multiindex column?
Also, important point is that every column has its own format (including headers), that's why for loop is used.

Upd:
Here is the output from pd.pivot_table():
[image]

Basically, the problem is that VALUE1 should have completely different format (green, bold, 5 decimals), same as VALUE2 (6 decimals). Also, as I have already mentioned, if you save the pivot table to excel and apply formatting the same way I do above in code, excel file throws the error when opening

Comment: Can we see a sample of your data and the output you want?